How to create fulltext index without specifying node label in Cypher
I tried to create a fulltext index for all nodes based on this documentation
This is the query I came up with:
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX full_text_docs
FOR (n)<-[:contains]-(d:DocumentFile) ON EACH [n.entity_id, d.entity_id]
IF NOT EXISTS

but I get the following error:
neo4j.exceptions.CypherSyntaxError: {code: Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError} {message: Invalid input ')': expected ":" (line 3, column 39 (offset: 76))
"                FOR (n)<-[:contains]-(d:DocumentFile) ON EACH [n.entity_id, d.entity_id]"
                       ^}

The query was derived from the two examples:
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX namesAndTeams FOR (n:Employee|Manager) ON EACH [n.name, n.team]

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX communications FOR ()-[r:REVIEWED|EMAILED]-() ON EACH [r.message]

where the first example uses n:label (but I don't want to specify a label) and the second uses a relationship but without specifying n (I want to specify n so I can index it).
How do I change the query so that it creates a fulltext index for all nodes matching (n)<-[:contains]-(d:DocumentFile)?
EDIT:
This does not work either
                CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX full_text_docs
                FOR (n:EntityNode)-[r:contains]-(d:DocumentFile) ON EACH [n.entity_id, d.entity_id]
                IF NOT EXISTS

Error:
neo4j.exceptions.CypherSyntaxError: {code: Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError} {message: Invalid input '-': expected "ON" (line 3, column 51 (offset: 88))
"                FOR (n:EntityNode)-[r:contains]-(d:DocumentFile) ON EACH [n.entity_id, d.entity_id]"
                                   ^}


It turns out I did not actually need to do it that way. It also is not possible to do what I asked for in Neo4j. See: https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/indexes/semantic-indexes/full-text-indexes/#create-full-text-indexes

When creating a full-text index, you need to specify the labels/relationship types and property names it should apply to.

So labels are required. Below is the alternative that works for my use case.
I can simply create the index twice, once for n and once for d but I really only need n since I am searching for n later on.
Here's how I did it:
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX nodes
IF NOT EXISTS
FOR (n:EntityNode) ON EACH [n.entity_id]

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX docs
IF NOT EXISTS
FOR (d:DocumentFile) ON EACH [d.entity_id]

I have previously added the label to all nodes that are not DocumentFile:
MATCH (n)
WHERE NOT n:EntityNode AND NOT n:DocumentFile
SET n :EntityNode

And here's how I did the search:
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes("nodes", $query_text) YIELD node as n, score
MATCH (n)<-[contains]-(d:DocumentFile)
RETURN n, d, score


You do not show any use of the docs index. Is it actually needed?

I realized that it's not necessary to index both, so it's not actually needed. I'm new to Cypher, just did not understand how the index was supposed to be built.

Since you cannot make an index on nodes without specifying a label, may I suggest you make a Uniqueness Constraint, which will include an index. This way the database will not allow for duplicates of your n.entity_id.
You could also add a label to ALL your nodes, lets say "Entity", so then you can have a single Uniqueness Constraint (and built in index) for all your entity_id properties, and they would never overlap, even across your existing node types.
Uniqueness Constraint Docs
If you use Enterprise Edition, and wanted to guarantee the existence of this entity_id you could also need add an Existence Constraint documented on the same page as above.
